# UICollectionView Lag/frame drop

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Good afternoon all my app is currently dropping frames and i am not sure how to fix it...im a bit lost.

hopefully you guys/gals can point me in the right direction.

I am currently using Kingfisher to download the images from my backend, everything works well with the exception of the scrolling it's a bit choppy when you scroll down.

the controller code is as followed maybe there's something wrong with it.

i am using storyboard and have removed and added the constraints...but ive had no luck.

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher

class WallpaperCVC: UICollectionViewController , UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

    var categoryId: String!
    var categoryName: String!
    var wallpaperBackend: Backend!
    var result:CGSize!
    // Header peralax
    fileprivate let headerId = "headerId"
    fileprivate let padding: CGFloat = 16



    @IBOutlet var wpMain: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = self.categoryName // Name to the controller or section selected
        // go go gadget data...
        getData()
        buttonGray()
        setupCollectionViewLayout()
        setupCollectionView()
    }

    func getData(){
        GLOBAL_BACKEND_DATA.removeAll()
        self.wallpaperBackend = Backend()
        self.wallpaperBackend.getWallByIdData(id: self.categoryId) { (god) in
            for post in god {
                let postData = post as! NSDictionary
                let wallpaperCVCId = postData.value(forKey: "id") as! String
                let wallpaperCVCFile = postData.value(forKey: "file") as! String
                let wallpaperCVCCategory = postData.value(forKey: "category") as! String
                let wallpaperCVCDownload = Int(postData.value(forKey: "download") as! String)

                GLOBAL_BACKEND_DATA.append(WallpaperModel(wallpaperModelId: wallpaperCVCId, wallpaperModelFile: wallpaperCVCFile, wallpaperModelCategoryId: wallpaperCVCCategory, wallpaperModelDownload: wallpaperCVCDownload!))
            }
         self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @IBAction func pressedAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // do your stuff here
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("you clicked on button \(sender.tag)")
    }
    func buttonGray(){
        let myButton = UIButton() // if you want to set the type use like UIButton(type: .RoundedRect) or UIButton(type: .Custom)
        let img = UIImage(named: "buttonA")
        myButton.setImage(img, for: .normal)
       // myButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        myButton.frame = CGRect(x: 15, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100)
        // shadow
        myButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        myButton.layer.shadowRadius = 4
        myButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5)
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pressedAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        // haptic feedback
        myButton.isHaptic = true
        myButton.hapticType = .impact(.medium)
        //floatbutton like this
        view.addSubview(myButton)
        myButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        myButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        // You only need one section for now
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Here call the wallpapers
        return GLOBAL_BACKEND_DATA.count
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // pulling & going to the controller
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "wallpapers", for: indexPath) as! WallpaperCVCell
        let godData = GLOBAL_BACKEND_DATA[indexPath.row]
        let imageURL = String(format:"%@uploads/image/%@", BASE_BACKEND_URL,godData.wallpaperModelFile) // calling wallpaperModel controller
        let escapedURL = imageURL.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        let urls = URL(string:escapedURL!)
        // if nothing load this...
        let loadImage = UIImage(named: "skullLoading")
        cell.collWallpaperImage.kf.setImage(with: urls, placeholder: loadImage)
        cell.collWallpaperImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity  // Showing a loading indicator while downloading
        // lets count the downloads
        let count = godData.wallpaperModelDownload as Int // calling wallpaperModel controller
        cell.collectionCount.text = String(count) //collection view cell count label
        cell.configure() // calling a function from the cell

        return cell
    }

    // Lets move over to the next controller
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("Tapped....Tapped go to the next controller..")
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "page") as! PageViewController
        vc.position = indexPath.row
        vc.categoryName = self.categoryName
        vc.transitioningDelegate = self
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

// MARK: - CollectionView Delegate
extension WallpaperCVC {
    // size images
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        result =  CGSize(width: 187, height: 314)
        if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
            result = CGSize(width: 160, height: 280)
        }
        if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
            result =  CGSize(width: 187, height: 314)
        }
        if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
            result = CGSize(width: 207, height: 320)
        }
        if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
            result = CGSize(width: 151, height: 200)
        }
        return result;
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {


            return UIEdgeInsets(top: 15, left: 8, bottom: 5, right: 8)
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 10
        }

     //size to all model screens to one.....NOW!!!!!!!!
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
            return CGSize(width: (width - 28)/2, height: 350) // width & height are the same to make a square cell
            }

}
// MARK: - CollectionView Layout Delegate
extension WallpaperCVC : UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout  {
    // Header peralax
    fileprivate func setupCollectionViewLayout() {
        let padding: CGFloat = 16
        if let layout = wpMain.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            layout.sectionInset = .init(top: padding, left: 0, bottom: padding, right: 0)
        }
    }
   // Header peralax
    fileprivate func setupCollectionView(){
        wpMain.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        wpMain.register(headerView.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: headerId)

    }
   // Header peralax
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        let headerView = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: kind, withReuseIdentifier: headerId, for: indexPath)

        return headerView
    }
    // Header peralax
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return .init(width: view.frame.width, height: 400)
      }
    }
```

the cell looks like this

```
import UIKit
import Spring
import UICountingLabel



class WallpaperCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
      // self.textLabel?.frame = self.bounds
    }

    func configure() {

            layer.shouldRasterize = true
            layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
            contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
            contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true
           // contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
          //  contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionCount: UICountingLabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var collWallpaperImage: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
}
```

&& here is the video...the initial scroll lags then it goes away but it does it everytime

[iPhone app lag video](https://youtu.be/XZm9c4G2JbE)

**EDIT:** Ok in the end i remode Kingfisher & installed SDWebImage this took care of the problem.

Comment: Can you share the code that is in your cell.configure() function?

Comment: So your problem is resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given code there is nothing that should cause the lag. If you could share a short video of the lag that might help understand the problem better.

And also if you could share the code that is in your cell.configure() method that would also help.

I do have a few suggestions for you that might help, you can try them on.

first of all you can move your device check

```
    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
        result = CGSize(width: 160, height: 280)
    }
    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
        result =  CGSize(width: 187, height: 314)
    }
    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
        result = CGSize(width: 207, height: 320)
    }
    if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
        result = CGSize(width: 151, height: 200)
    }
```

in viewDidLoad which will help your collection view layout to size your cells faster and not having to check this every time the user scrolls

Something like this

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return result;
}
```

and

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = self.categoryName // Name to the controller or section selected
    setupDeviceSize()
    // go go gadget data...
    getData()
    buttonGray()
    setupCollectionViewLayout()
    setupCollectionView()
}

func setupDeviceSize(){

  if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_5 {
    result = CGSize(width: 160, height: 280)
  }
  if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6 {
    result =  CGSize(width: 187, height: 314)
  }
  if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_6P {
    result = CGSize(width: 207, height: 320)
  }
  if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {
    result = CGSize(width: 151, height: 200)
  }
}
```

Second is you can create a global variable for your place holder image

```
let loadImage = UIImage(named: "skullLoading")
```

and use that in your cellForItemAtIndexpath, which will again save loading of the placeholder image every time your cellForItemAtIndexpath is called.

You should always keep your cellForItemAtIndexpath as light as possible for a smooth scrolling experience.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have added the cell & a link to the video...as you can see it only lags initially and ones then it goes away...it does it for both of that categories that are over 20 items.

Comment: i made the changes as requested but the lag is still there.../-: